# Kivy clocks issue(something doubles every time)

Tags: python, kivy

So my problem is that whenever i create a new game by create_game() method something strange happens and everything starts to move 2 times faster i think it is due to a Clock issue but i am not sure. My question is what can i do to make it run in normal pace. Here is code:

```
def create_game(self):
    for i in range(1,11):
        for j in range(15):
            brick = Brick(pos = [self.width/15*j,self.height - self.height/30*i - self.height/6], size_hint = [1/15,1/30] )
            a = random.randint(1,3)
            if(a!=3):
                self.brick_container.add_widget(brick)
    ball = Ball(pos = (self.paddle.center_x, self.paddle.height + 1), size_hint = [None,None], size = [self.width/50,self.width/50])
    self.ball_container.add_widget(ball)
    self.game_on_pause = True
    self.update()


def serve_ball(self):
    self.ball_container.children[0].velocity = Vector(3,3)

if(len(self.ball_container.children) == 0):
        self.level += 1
        self.brick_container.clear_widgets()
        self.ball_container.clear_widgets()
        self.bonus_container.clear_widgets()
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)
        self.create_game()


    Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
```

Comment: provide a [mcve], and read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Save the *Clock.schedule_once* to a variable, *event* and replace `Clock.unschedule(self.update)` with `self.event.cancel()`

```
if(len(self.ball_container.children) == 0):
        ...
        self.bonus_container.clear_widgets()
        self.event.cancel()
        self.create_game()

    self.event = Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
```

## Note

An alternative is to use [Trigger events](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#trigger-events).

> Each time you call trigger(), it will schedule a single call of your
>   callback. If it was already scheduled, it will not be rescheduled.

```
self.trigger = Clock.create_trigger(my_callback, 1.0 / 60.0)
self.trigger()    # schedule it
self.trigger.cancel()    # cancel / unschedule it
```